# .SWF Object Shrinking in IE 8

Tags: html, wordpress, internet-explorer, flash, swfobject

I am having an issue in WordPress. I've embedded a .swf as an object, but in IE 8 it shows really small. I've attached a screenshot of the IE issue. It's that really small picture on the left. To see a working version, check out the [page here](http://pplsusquehanna.wpengine.com/how-it-works/) on another browser.

I would love to disregard this issue, but unfortunately our company runs on IE so I need to fix this.

This is all created in WordPress. The .swf is hosted externally. Here is the code:

```
<object width="680px" height="300px">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.pplweb.com/ppl-generation/~/media/PPLWeb/Generation/Media/PPL%20Susquehanna/nuclear.swf">
<embed src="http://www.pplweb.com/ppl-generation/~/media/PPLWeb/Generation/Media/PPL%20Susquehanna/nuclear.swf" width="100" height="100">
</embed>
</object>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed it using [SWFObject](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject), it's the most reliable way to insert SWF files. WordPress already comes bundled with it, so you just need `wp_enqueue_script('swfobject');`, and then use the script embedding accordingly.

Or you can use a plugin: [wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=swfobject](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=swfobject).